# Does Hawkular REST API have a swagger specification?

Tags: swagger, hawkular

The documentation subtitle for 
[www.hawkular.org/docs/rest/rest-metrics.html](http://www.hawkular.org/docs/rest/rest-metrics.html)
is "Auto-generated swagger documentation"

I can't find the swagger specification file in either JSON or YAML format, in the site or the repo.

Does one exist for either hawkular-metrics or [hawkular-alerts](http://www.hawkular.org/docs/rest/rest-alerts.html)?

Is this a useful way to generate an interface for a Hawkular service. Or is there a better way?